# Getting a Value from a dropdown populated from an SQL database

Tags: php, html, input, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have populated a drop down from my MySQL Database successfully. I am now wanting to be able to extracte the value from this dropdown. When ever I extract the value from the dropdown it is only the position value of the value in the list.

Here is the working drop down below:

```
<?php

include_once("connection.php"); 

 function fill_name($connect)  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $sql = "SELECT name, id FROM notes";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';  
      }  
      return $output;  
 }  

 ?>  

 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Patient Notes View</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           </script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container">  
                <form action="dropdown_selection.php" method="post">  
                     <select name="name" id="name">  
                          <option value="">Show All Patients</option>  
                           <?php echo fill_name($connect); ?> 
                     </select>  
                     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

                </form>  
           </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      </body>  
 </html>
```

And here is the page it then refers to:

```
<?php
$patient_name = $_POST['name'];
echo $patient_name

?>
```

The output is either 1,2,3,4, but I am wanting it to output what is is selected in the dropdown.

Thnks for your help

Comment: the value doesn't match up with the IDs?

Comment: the output is correct as you set option value to be ID, not NAME -> <option value="'.$row["id"].'"> therefore you get IDs

Comment: The number is the item's ID, not necessarily its position. Make the `value` the `name`, not the `id`, or query on the next page based on the `id`.

Comment: thanks for that Im new to php so I didn't realise thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either change the `value` of your elements, or remove them. If the element has no value its content will be sent as the value.

> The content of this attribute represents the value to be submitted with the form, should this option be selected. If this attribute is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

So either:

```
$output .= '<option value="'.$row["name"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';
```

or

```
$output .= '<option>'.$row["name"].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is number is correct as you set option value to be `ID`, not `NAME` -> `<option value="'.$row["id"].'">` therefore you get `ID`s

Comment: is that answer to your own question ? ^^